# How Add title to TAG in Angular Framework with JS light?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I try to add title to tag that appears 6 times in code:**

```
    var a = $document.find('md-checkbox');
    a.after('<span title="title">i</span>');
```

**So I try to find tag by text content, but it is not working:**

```
     app.controller('FacetExactAfterController', ['angularLoad', '$document', function (angularLoad, $document) {

        var text = 'TEXT';
        var wrappedResult = angular.element.binding(text);
        wrappedResult.after('<span title="title">title text</span>');

    }]);

    app.component('prmFacetExactAfter', {
        bindings: {parentCtrl: '<'},
        controller: 'FacetExactAfterController',
    });
```

Comment: Your code is missing a space before the word `title`: `compensate-padding-left"title="Title"`

Comment: It is not the reason I don't know the right PRM name will be